# How to load CSS file dynamically by taking css file path from backend only?

Tags: css, typescript, angular7

I have to load css according to some parameters, that come from backend.
If RoleID is 1 then I want to load role1.scss and for RoleID is 2 then I want to load role2.scss. Here i'm taking css files path from backend.This selected css should apply to the whole application.

In component I have written
`this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', this.cssLink );`
this.cssLink is the path of css file taken from backend

In my index.html

`<link id="theme" href="styles.scss">`

I have also tried

```
 require('style-loader!' + this.cssLink);
```

It gives error:
Error: Cannot find module 'style-loader!src/app/role1.scss'

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
function loadcssfile(filename) {
    var fileref = document.createElement("link")
    fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
    fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

loadcssfile("here your css file path", "css");
```